# How I copy a list in python, if I want the orginal list has no effect on the copy one?

Tags: python

I have a list with some set in it, the list looks like this:

```
[{1,2},{2,3},{0,1}]
```

How can I copy it to a new one, and they will not have any effect with each other?

I have used these functions, but no way to change them.

```
a = [{1,2}, {0}, {0}, set()]
b = a[:]
b = copy.copy(a)
```

Comment: use deep copy. Regards.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: ok, think you, I have solved the problem with deepcopy.

Comment: deep copy is not ideal esp in sitatuoins where you can avoid it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import copy
 
a=[{1,2},{2,3},{0,1}]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know your `list` has a fixed structure and only contains a `set` of int values, it might be more efficient to use `set.copy()`.

On my machine, it appears to be about **25x** faster overall than `copy.deepcopy`.

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from timeit import timeit

S = [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {0, 1}]

print('set.copy:      ', timeit('[s.copy() for s in S]', globals=globals()))
print('copy.deepcopy: ', timeit('deepcopy(S)', globals=globals()))
```

When running this on Mac M1:

```
set.copy:       0.24300479097291827
copy.deepcopy:  6.54383279196918
```